# EF get record for each item

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Hello guys this is what I have so far.

```
public List<Word> GetWords(string[] words)
{
      return DbContext.Words.Where(w => words.Contains(w.Value.ToLower());
}
```

The problem is that when I pass for example List containing two same words I am getting one entity. What can be an effective way of getting entity for each word even if it's duplicate?

Answer (score 2):

Given this simplified test case, where `sourceData` represents your `DbContext.Words`:

```
var sourceData = new string[]
{
    "a",
    "b",
    "c"
};

var wordsToFind = new string[]
{
    "a",
    "a"
};
```

A silly way would be to execute the query for each requested input:

```
var foundWords = wordsToFind.Select(w => 
    sourceData.Where(s => s.Contains(w.ToLower()))).ToList();
```

Or you could execute the query once, then duplicate the results per input by executing the query in-memory again:

```
var foundWords = sourceData.Where(w => 
    wordsToFind.Contains(w.ToLower())).ToList();

var result = wordsToFind.SelectMany(w => 
    foundWords.Where(f => 
        f.Contains(w.ToLower()))).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you want substring or equal words, following query returns multiple records but checking for the same word not substring.

```
public List<Word> GetWords(string[] words)
{
      var results = from word in DbContext.Words.ToArray()
                        join str in words on word.ToLower() equals str
                    select word;

      return results.ToList();          

}
```

**EDIT:** First get the filtered records from the database and then join it with the array again to get multiple records. Same thing checking twice. Stored procedure would be more efficient for a huge collection.

```
public List<Word> GetWords(string[] words)
{
      var results = from word in DbContext.Words
                          .Where(w =>  words.Contains(w.Value.ToLower())
                          .ToArray()
                        join str in words on str.Contains(word.ToLower()) 
                                       equals true
                    select word;

      return results.ToList();               

}
```

Comment: I don't think Entity Framework supports joins against in-memory collections.

Comment: No, I have converted it to an array (in memory) before joining.

Comment: I see. That would run, but it won't be efficient if the table is large.

Comment: Agree !, what are the other options.? may be a stored procedure with a csv .

Comment: I was thinking of issuing the OP's query to the database, then using your join on just the returned results.

Comment: @Douglas: modified. I think that would produce expected output.